# NuGet content file not found at runtime when running project that uses it

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I have a 3 class library solution which has the following dependency diagram

```
LanguageDetector.NTextCat.DependencyInjection --> LanguageDetector.NTextCat --> LanguageDetector
```

The project `LanguageDetector.NTextCat` requires an xml file to work, because it reads from it at runtime. When running tests in that project, all is good, everything works properly.

It reads it with

```
var factory = new RankedLanguageIdentifierFactory();
var rankedLanguageIdentifier = factory.Load("Wiki82.profile.xml");
```

which basically it does some

```
File.OpenRead("Wiki82.profile.xml")
```

behind the scenes.

I have the following in the `LanguageDetector.NTextCat.csproj` with a `Pack="True"`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
        <Title>$(AssemblyName)</Title>
        <VersionPrefix>0.6.0</VersionPrefix>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\LanguageDetector\LanguageDetector.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="NTextCat" Version="0.3.65" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Wiki82.profile.xml" Pack="true">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

so when I pack it `dotnet pack -o foo` I can see the 3 `nupkg` and the `Rubiko.LanguageDetector.NTextCat.0.6.0.nupkg` has a `content` folder with the `Wiki82.profile.xml` file.

The problem is when I use these nuget libraries with my main project. When running tests I can see it fails at runtime with a `FileNotFoundException`

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/media/diegosasw/data/src/microservices/my-command-service/test/My.CmdService.FunctionalTests/bin/Debug/net6.0/Wiki82.profile.xml'.
File name: '/media/diegosasw/data/src/microservices/my-command-service/test/My.CmdService.FunctionalTests/bin/Debug/net6.0/Wiki82.profile.xml'
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path)
   at NTextCat.BasicProfileFactoryBase`1.Load(String inputFilePath, Func`2 filterPredicate)
   at LanguageDetector.NTextCat.NTextCatLanguageDetector.Detect(String text, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at My.CmdService.Domain.Models.ChatAggregate.AddAgentMessage(DateTime createdOn, Guid agentId, String message, IImmutableList`1 validationErrorsToSkip, ILanguageDetector languageDetector, IAgentMessageValidator agentMessageValidator) in /media/diegosasw/data/src/microservices/my-command-service/src/My.CmdService.Domain/Models/ChatAggregate.cs:line 205
```

It is true, the xml file is not in the output folder.

I have tried adding the file as `Content` and as `EmbeddedResource` but there's no luck. The file is not copied across from the nuget package's content files to the `net6.0/Wiki82.profile.xml`

**How to do that?**

Comment: `The file is not copied across from the nuget package's content files to the net6.0/Wiki82.profile.xml`Can you try to copy the xml file to `net6.0/Wiki82.profile.xml` manually?

Comment: Yes, and if I do that it works. But I would like to have a solution where I don't need to manually copy the file or manually have it at the main assembly/process, but rather having the imported nuget library reading it from its own nuget library